# How to extend from an InnerClass in kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Basically what I want is something like this in kotlin:

```
public class BindingViewHolder<T extends ViewDataBinding> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {}

//it should be:

public class BindingViewHolder<T: ViewDataBinding> :
       RecyclerView.ViewHolder() {}
```

I'm using extending java classes so I don't know if this is possible, Android Studio tell me that the type is expected but neither writing the type inside <> or inside () it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` [`constructor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#RecyclerView.ViewHolder(android.view.View)) requires an item view passed in:

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder (View itemView)
```

You have to pass a base class constructor parameter from derived class i.e:

```
class BindingViewHolder<T : ViewDataBinding>(binding:T) 
    : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```